# How do I use an ASP.NET server script to apply edits to an existing JSON file?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json

I was trying to do this in PHP by the parameters of my project prohibit me from using PHP unfortunately. (Microsoft products only, uni project, I'm sure you've been there)

Anyway, here is my JSON file:

```
{
"nextid" : 3,
"ingredients" : [
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "onion",
    "kilojoules": 180,
    "quantity": 1,
    "measurement": "whole",
    "nutrition": [
        {"value": "Fat Total", "quantity": 110},
        {"value": "Saturated Fat", "quantity": 46},
        {"value": "Sodium", "quantity": 4},
        {"value": "Carbohydrates Total", "quantity": 10000},
        {"value": "Sugar", "quantity": 5000},
        {"value": "Fibre", "quantity": 2000},
        {"value": "Proten", "quantity": 1000}
    ]},

{
    "id" : 2,
    "name": "carrot",
    "kilojoules": 56,
    "quantity": 1,
    "measurement": "whole",
    "nutrition": [
        {"value": "Fat Total", "quantity": 66},
        {"value": "Saturated Fat", "quantity": 11},
        {"value": "Sodium", "quantity": 26},
        {"value": "Carbohydrates Total", "quantity": 3000},
        {"value": "Sugar", "quantity": 2000},
        {"value": "Fibre", "quantity": 1000},
        {"value": "Proten", "quantity": 279}
    ]}
]

}
```

And here is the javascript that loads it into my html page:

```
function downloadIngredients() {
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("/data/ingredientsInfo.js", function (result) {
        try
        {
            ingJson = result;
            ingredients = result.ingredients;
            ingredients.sort(orderByNameAscending);
            buildListBox(ingredients);
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert(err.message);
        }
    });
});
}
```

I have no problems with manipulating the objects while it's loaded and stringifying it to pass back. That part I'm stuck on is I know bugger all about ASP.NET or even how to BEGIN constructing a script to handle it. Total noob, I don't know the anatomy of the script, is it just a c# object with special references in it? I'm having a hard time finding a straight answer and I just need someone to spell it out to me like I'm an idiot.

How do I take my stringified json file and update it on the server?
**EDIT:** Sorry, for clarity. Lets say I change the carrot's kilojoule value to 60, how can apply that change to the json file so the next time a carrot is retrieved it reflects the change.

Additionally, I'd like to be able to add new ingredients to it that draw from the nextid value of their parent object and subsequently increment it, but I figure once I know how apply an edit I'll know enough to figure the rest out.

For the record, I know I shouldn't be using JSON files like this. This kind of data management should be happening inside a database. But I'm stuck with this for now, however brittle and dangerous it turns out to be.

I'd appreciate any help I can get. Thanks :)

Comment: Not sure I understand the questions right. I guess what you want to do is take the html edits made by user, form a json out of it and post it to server where it gets saved as user?

Comment: I want to update the original JSON. Sorry I'll edit the question to reflect what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Perhaps it's a razor script I'm trying to make. Does that sound plausible?